# Compare a string value in excel using PHPExcel parser

Tags: php, string, phpexcel

I am trying to parse an excel spreadsheet using [phpexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library in php but I can't get the logic correct for comparing a value in the cell.

[image]
[image]

I am using following code to read values in excel:

```
$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow("10", $row)->getValue()
```

The HTML output is

```
â˜‘
```

And when I try to find all the rows with this value  using the following logic I never get the equation true.

```
  for ($row = 5; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
        if ($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow("10", $row)->getValue() == 'â˜‘') {
            echo 'rowno ' . $row . ' ' . 'BOOKED';
            echo '<br/>';
        }else{
           echo strtolower($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow("10", $row)->getValue()) ;
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }
```

Could someone please let me know what I am doing incorrectly here?

Comment: What is the real value, which is entered in the Excel cell? Or is the HTML output correct?

Comment: @Geshode it looks like it is just a checkbox..it could be ascii. I have updated my question with an image.

Answer (score 2):

In the [PHP Developer Documentation](http://www.colpsic.org.co/PHPExcel/Documentation/PHPExcel%20developer%20documentation.pdf), which I found through Google, they use Row- and Celliterators as follows:

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $cell->getValue();
    }
}
```

Using this you could use the following to compare it with the wanted value:

```
$check = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getValue();

foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $value = $cell->getValue();
        if($check == $value){
            //what you want to happen, if it is true
        } else {
            //what you want to happen, if it is false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I am doing, the problem is the value is not a normal html value. I think I have now resolved it and will update my question with the answer. thank you again.

Comment: Good, that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the value in the excel column is quoted_printable. I found out this by using following code:

```
 foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){
            echo 'Row '. $row .'-'. mb_convert_encoding($var2, 'UTF-8', $chr)." : ".$chr."<br>";
 }
```

this displays what encoding is for the value. My case was **Quoted-Printable** I found the solution [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) to encode quoted printable characters.